# How to view 'only those commits' where were added since the repo was cloned?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a git repository

```
git clone xyz.git
```

1. I 
   modified a file (say 'a.txt'), added and committed it locally.
2. Again,  I modified a file (say 'b.txt'), added and committed it locally.
3. I did NOT push the changes to remote

> The git log produces the entire list of commits.

I would like to view only the commits which were added since the repository was cloned.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try `git reflog <branch>`. The last entry in the bottom of the output is either the first commit you made or the tip commit when the repository was cloned.

Comment: I do not recommend using the reflog.  This will tell you the commit(s) to which the local ref for that branch has pointed, which under some reasonable circumstances might get what you want; except the reflog is not permanent.

Answer (score 1):

"Since cloned" is difficult, or even impossible, depending on what information you specifically saved right after cloning, or how long it has been since then.  But it's also not *useful*, so it doesn't matter how difficult it is: "since cloned" is the wrong *question* to ask.  (For a very flawed analogy, imagine trying to catch an escaped animal.  The interesting question is not where it was three weeks ago, but rather where it is *now*.)

When you have a remote—which is just a short name, like `origin`, for another URL where there is another Git repository that contains commits—the interesting question is not *What do I have that they didn't back when I ran `git clone`?* but rather *What do I have that they don't have **the last time I saw what they have**?*  And *that* is a question Git will answer, because your Git records, in your repository, its memory of what they had the last time you connected to them.

If you have a branch `master` that your Git made from their branch `master`, your Git also has its memory of "where their `master` was, the last time we talked to them."  That memory is stored in `origin/master`.  Therefore, you can run:

```
git log origin/master..master
```

which means "show me what I have on my `master`, that is not also on `origin/master`".

If you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

(which you can do at any time), that tells your Git: *Connect to the other Git over at `origin`, and pick up whatever new items they have, and update my `origin/master` and other `origin/` remote-tracking branch names.*

Similarly, when you run:

```
git push origin master
```

that tells your Git: *Connect to the other Git at `origin`, give them my new commits, and ask them to set **their** `master` to the same thing as my `master`.*  If they—the other Git at `origin`—agree to the request to update their master, your Git records that in your `origin/master`, since your Git knows their Git is updated.

Answer (score 0):

@torek brings up a good point, which is that it's tricky to tell when a repository was *cloned*. However, it's very easy to get a list of commits between your *remote* branch and your *local* branch.

Use

```
git log HEAD...origin/your_branch
```

`HEAD` is where the tip of your local branch currently sits.

`origin/your_branch` is where the repo has the tip of the remote branch

---

From the `git help log` page:

```
git log [<options>] [<revision range>] [[--] <path>...]

   <revision range>
       Show only commits in the specified revision range. When no <revision range> is specified, it
       defaults to HEAD (i.e. the whole history leading to the current commit).  origin..HEAD
       specifies all the commits reachable from the current commit (i.e.  HEAD), but not from origin.
       For a complete list of ways to spell <revision range>, see the Specifying Ranges section of
       gitrevisions(7).
```